# Is it OK to Move Common ViewController Presentation Logic into Presentation Helper Classes

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to use layers to make sure I separate everything into it's correct areas in my Swift / iOS / Xcode 6 project. The question, ultimately, **is: is it OK / a common practice to move commonly used presentation-level logic to a separate presentation helper class instead of writing it over and over in multiple view controllers with little or no difference?**

Here is an example to tie this in and give context:

One of the things I am aiming to do is use a UITableView to display report data. This UITableView will contain 7-10 rows, depending upon the user's preferences (nsuserdefaults). Each row contains a localized string for a label, and some decimal value.

As an example one row could be "Sales made this week:  $500.00"

I have a reporting service class that's responsible for talking to the database and getting back / instantiating a report object. This report object contains the raw data for the report, i.e. how much you made this week, this month, this year, etc. Whether the user wants to show all these values or not is irrelevant to the service - it simply gets everything.

So since I have 3 view models that use this same report, I thought it would be wrong to rewrite the same code each time that checks the user's preferences, then creates/binds an array to the UITable and matches the labels with the report values from the object returned by the service.

A better way, I thought, was to create a presentation-level helper class whose job would be to take a report object (the thing I mentioned before that contains the report values), take a user's preferences, and then more generically combine them to create a list of localized strings matched with their respective report values, agnostic to what the view controller wants. Maybe if that requirement changes later (where different view controllers need more customization) I could use flags or different function names within that class.

This way all I have to do is something like

```
 var report = ReportHelper.GenerateReport(reportData, userSettings)
```

and now report would be an object that could look like this (mock JSON data):

{"Amount made this week":"$100", "Amount made this month":"$500", "Amount made this year": "$10,000"}

And I can use this in any view controller.

The alternate is to just hard code those above values (obviously still pulling localized strings) but I don't know if I adding all those strings + checks based on user preferences + formatting. Seems more elegant to move it away.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know too little about your problem to provide the definite answer, but basically you have 2 options:
- inheritance
- composition

I personally like inheritance although it is often stated you should choose composition over inheritance.

Your helper sounds somewhat like composition, so that would be the preferred setup. With your specific problem as I understand it, inheritance would lead to a duplication of data, so that is one more argument to choose composition.

So all in all you seem to be about right

*Edit:*
Inheritance is an "is" relationship, whereas composition is a "has" relationship.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition for more details about composition.
And see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance for more info why and when to choose composition

Comment: Thanks so much for this explanation. When you say composition, typically that means a class has some sort of member that is itself another class right? In this case i'm using a service whose responsibility is to provide me something, so that means it's composition?

Comment: Exactly - see the links I added